# mouse scrolling not working on iframe (youtube embed code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

When the mouse is on iframe, scrolling doesn't work. I already tried pointer-events CSS but after use this video didn't play.  what should I do now for scrolling and also video should be played like present?

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vGvbxj4-N4k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Please include all the necessary details in your question. Please don't ask people to go to any random sites.